# Replacing array elements in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm trying to replace an element in my array and my code doesn't seem to work.

```
my @wholeloop = (split //, $loop);

for my $i (0 .. $#wholeloop ) {
    if ( $wholeloop[$i] eq "i" ) {
        $wholeloop[$i] =~ htmlinsert($offset);
        $offset++
    }
}
```

I've read about problematics of doing stuff while iterating through an array, and maybe is there a better solution. I'm trying to replace specific occurences of a character in a string, and array seemed as a reasonable tool to use.

Comment: If you know the character to replace, using a regex might be preferable. E.g. `$loop =~ s/([iaeou])/htmlinsert($1)/ge`. Note that I have no idea what `$offset` is in your code, and why you use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically - when iterating on a loop, you don't need to do it via:

```
for ( 0..$#array) {
```

Because

```
for ( @array ) {
```

will do the same thing, but with an added advantage of `$_` being an alias to the array variable.

```
for my $element ( @wholeloop ) {
    if ( $element eq "i" ) {
       $element = htmlinsert($offset++);
    }
}
```

`$element` is an *alias* so if you change it, you change the array. (`$_` will do the same, but I dislike using it when I don't have to, because I think it make less clear code. This is a style/choice matter, rather than a technical one).

However for searching and replacing an element in a string – like you're doing – then you're probably better off using one of the other things perl does really well – regular expressions and pattern replacement. I can't give an example easily though, without knowing what `htmlinsert` returns.

Something like though:

```
 $loop =~ s/i/newvalue/g;
```

Will replace all instances of `i` with a `new value`.

Answer (score 2):

`=~` is Perl's "match regular expression" operator, so unless `htmlinsert()` returns a regex, it's probably not what you meant to do. You probably want to use `=`.

A more Perlish way to do this, though, might be to use the `map` function. `map` takes a block and an array and runs the block with each element of the array in `$_`, returning all the values returned by that block. For example:

```
my @wholeloop = map {
    $_ eq "i" ? htmlinsert($offset++) : $_;
} split //, $loop;
```

(The `?` and `:` perform an "if/else" in a single line; they're borrowed from C. `map` is borrowed from functional programming languages.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use foreach. It is the most suitable for what you are trying to do here

```
my @array;  
foreach ( @array ) {  
    $_ =~ whatever your replacement is;  
}
```

Now, like Sobrique said, unless htmlinsert returns a RegEx value, that isn't going to work. Also, if you could give us context for "$offset", and what its purpose is, that would be really helpful.